# Vector taking less time to get populated than ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, vector, collections

I was going through the following article:

[Understanding Collections and Thread Safety in Java](http://www.codejava.net/java-core/collections/understanding-collections-and-thread-safety-in-java)

The article says:

> You know, Vector and Hashtable are the two collections exist early in Java history, and they are designed for thread-safe from the start (if you have chance to look at their source code, you will see their methods are all synchronized!). However, they quickly expose poor performance in multi-threaded programs. As you may know, synchronization requires locks which always take time to monitor, and that reduces the performance.

**[I've also done a benchmark using Caliper; please hear me out on this]**

A sample code has also been provided:

```
public class CollectionsThreadSafeTest {

    public void testVector() {
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        Vector<Integer> vector = new Vector<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10_000_000; i++) {
            vector.addElement(i);
        }

        long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long totalTime = endTime - startTime;
        System.out.println("Test Vector: " + totalTime + " ms");
    }

    public void testArrayList() {
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10_000_000; i++) {
            list.add(i);
        }

        long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long totalTime = endTime - startTime;
        System.out.println("Test ArrayList: " + totalTime + " ms");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CollectionsThreadSafeTest tester = new CollectionsThreadSafeTest();

        tester.testVector();
        tester.testArrayList();
    }
}
```

The output they have provided for the above code is as follows:

```
Test Vector: 9266 ms
Test ArrayList: 4588 ms
```

But when I ran it in my machine, it gave me the following result:

```
Test Vector: 521 ms
Test ArrayList: 2273 ms
```

I found this to be quite odd. I thought **doing a micro benchmark would be better**. So, I wrote a benchmark for the above using caliper. The code is as follows:

```
public class CollectionsThreadSafeTest extends SimpleBenchmark {

    public static final int ELEMENTS = 10_000_000;

    public void timeVector(int reps) {
        for (int i = 0; i < reps; i++) {
            Vector<Integer> vector = new Vector<>();
            for (int k = 0; k < ELEMENTS; k++) {
                vector.addElement(k);
            }
        }
    }

    public void timeArrayList(int reps) {
        for (int i = 0; i < reps; i++) {
            List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int k = 0; k < ELEMENTS; k++) {
                list.add(k);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] classesToTest = { CollectionsThreadSafeTest.class.getName() };
        Runner.main(classesToTest);
    }
}
```

But I got a similar result:

```
 0% Scenario{vm=java, trial=0, benchmark=ArrayList} 111684174.60 ns; ?=18060504.25 ns @ 10 trials
50% Scenario{vm=java, trial=0, benchmark=Vector} 67701359.18 ns; ?=17924728.23 ns @ 10 trials

benchmark    ms linear runtime
ArrayList 111.7 ==============================
   Vector  67.7 ==================

vm: java
trial: 0
```

I'm kinda confused. What is happening here? Am I doing something wrong here (that would be really embarrassing) ?

If this is the expected behavior, then what is the explanation behind this?

---

**Update #1**

After reading [@Kayaman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2541560/kayaman)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43602916/6042824), I ran the caliper tests by changing the values of the initial capacities of both the `Vector` and the `ArrayList`. Following are the timings (in ms):

```
Initial Capacity    Vector  ArrayList
-------------------------------------
10_000_000          49.2    67.1
10_000_001          48.9    71.2
10_000_010          48.1    61.2
10_000_100          43.9    70.1
10_001_000          45.6    70.6
10_010_000          44.8    68.0
10_100_000          52.8    64.6
11_000_000          52.7    71.7
20_000_000          74.0    51.8
-------------------------------------
```

Thanks for all the inputs :)

Comment: Small note: having synchronized methods does not make a class thread-safe, except under certain usage patterns. For example, given a `Vector<Foo> foos` with one occurrence of `foo1` in the list, the sequence `foos.remove(foo1); foos.add(foo1)` run by two threads more-or-less simultaneously can wind up with two occurrences of `foo1` in the list, or just one.

Comment: Regardless of the outcome of your benchmark, flawed as it is, you shouldn't use these legacy classes, `Hashtable` and `Vector`. It's not a question of speed or thread "safety" but of using the non-obsolescent replacements, which lack the excess cruft of the legacy types. It's been nineteen years; plenty of time to get used to the replacements.

Comment: @LewBloch Is using Caliper also bad or is their method bad in general?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not really testing the `add()` method here. You're testing the different ways that a `Vector` and an `ArrayList` grow. A `Vector` doubles in size when it's full, but an `ArrayList` has some more refined logic to prevent the internal array from growing exponentially and wasting memory.

If you run your test with a > 10000000 initial capacity for both classes, they won't need to resize and you'll be profiling just the adding part.

Comment: So, if I specify the size, I'll be able to get the actual times?

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "actual". You'll be removing the resizing from the equation. The resizing is faster on a `Vector` because after a while the internal capacity has grown huge and there's no more need to resize, whereas `ArrayList` grows in a calmer manner, saving memory but requiring more resizes if you haven't planned beforehand.

Comment: I set the initial capacity as 10_000_000 and then ran the caliper test again. Got `ArrayList: 67.1 ms` and `Vector: 49.2 ms`. So, kinda similar to what I've been getting.

Comment: I tried with various initial capacities > `10_000_000`. Its only at `20_000_000` that I got something different. Got `Vector: 74.0 ms` and `ArrayList: 51.8 ms`.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Caliper. JMH seems to be the most popular in the benchmarks I've seen here.

Comment: Ok. I'll have a look at JMH too. Also, can you give an explanation for the initial capacity bit. Ideally, for any value >= `10_000_000` should be enough for ArrayList to perform better than Vector, right?

Comment: It's not a good idea to make guesses like that in benchmarking. First you need to duplicate the results with JMH to make sure it's not an error in benchmarking, then if you're still interested you can look into it more.

Comment: Ok Cool... Will look into it and maybe get back to this thread :)

Answer (score 0):

The vector is expected to be slower in multithreaded environment. It is expected to be lightweight in your case. Better do the tests with adding these items from 10000 different threads

Comment: Ok. But what about the output they have provided for the sample code in the article? They are simply timing the add operations without using threads.

Comment: This doesn't explain why it's *faster* in a single-threaded environment.

Answer (score -1):

Both ArrayList and Vector have the same add method:

```
ensureCapacity();
    elementData[elementCount++] = newElement;
```

The difference is only one. Vector's add method is synchronized and ArrayList's is not. From theory synchronized methods are slower than non-synchronized.

To improve performance of add method you have to specify `initialCapacity` in constructor or call method `ensureCapacity`. This creates internal array as long as you need and so no need to recreate it.

Comment: How does this answer the question?